# Bad Rounding of simtime_t values using the CSV export

Tags: omnet++

Used Versions: **OMNeT++ 5.0** with **iNET 3.4.0**

During some data analysis I noticed that the CSV-export of the analysis tool rounds values like **0.01146575** to **0.0114658**. Even if I set the precision to the maximum value of 18.

Here some parts of my code: 
In .ned I declared the recording using the type 'simtime_t':

```
@signal[timestamp](type="simtime_t");
@statistic[timestamp](title="timestamp"; record=mean);
```

At the top of my .cc I declared the signals:

```
simsignal_t timestampSignal;
timestampSignal = registerSignal("timestamp");
```

and somewhere in my code I got:

```
sintime_t myTime = ... 
emit(timestamp, myTime);
```

Browsing my results in the .anf file I see the right timestamps, but when i export the data via CSV-export I get the bad rounding.

I think myTime is internally converted to a double value. I don't really know the reason, because I set the type of my signal to 'simtime_t'. The mentioned export-precision of '18' should normally be precise enough to display such values.

Is there anything I can do to avoid the rounding of my values? The .octave-exports seems to work fine, but I can't process this file-format in the way I want to.

Comment: Additional observation: copying values via the clipboard also seems to provide the complete values without any rounding...

Comment: Did you try the [standalone scavetool](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ana-sim:scavetool)? Export to CSV is also available there...

Comment: An export via scavetool using
`scavetool scalar -p "name(\timestamp:mean\")" -O output.csv -F csv General-*.sca`
brought the same issue like mentioned above.
Now I am trying to export as .mat file for MATLAB, but using the scavetool there is some header information I can't handle with MATLAB (complains 'Unable to read MAT-file'). Examining the created .mat file shows that there is much information about runs, module names, scalar names etc.

Comment: I think it might be time for a bug report on the [OMNeT Bugtracker](https://dev.omnetpp.org/bugs/view_all_bug_page.php).
You could also try if older versions of OMNeT (5.0 or 4.6 if you are using the 5.1 prereleases) have the same issue or if it is a problem with the newest version.

Comment: Can it be, that this only appears with scalar data?
I exported some vector data and it is complete with the numeric precision I selected...

Comment: This is indeed more a bug report than a question for SO, so I encourage you to report it on bugs.omnetpp.org for tracking. We may be able to fix this for the next release candidate.

Comment: @DirkHennsen: did you try the latest OMNeT++ 5.1 rc3? 
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/omnetpp/zDH6Tz-5rUA/LvI6A8-OCgAJ

Comment: @Michael Kirsche: No, i didn't try the version 5.1. As a workaround i wrote a bash-script using `grep`, `awk` and `cut`. It processes the generated OMNET-results and outputs a txt-file for my evaluation in Matlab.

Comment: @DirkHennsen, definitely try the new OMNeT 5.1 version. Take a look at the change logs, the output result generators and export formats have been updated and extended.